# How to limit query results with Mysql

Tags: mysql

Newbie question:

I've got an email message table that's got a message_id field (primary key field) and other fields like body, receiver_id, sender_id and parent_id. The parent_id field is what connects messages of the same thread together when user replies to a message.

Right now i have a simple query that looks up all the messages under a specific reciever_id and returns them. The problem is I want to also check to see if 2 or more messages have got the same parent_id and if so, i only want the most recent messsage returned.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

I thought about using a CASE statment but wasn't sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a timestamp to the field for when it was submitted. You could them use something similar to the following:

```
SELECT body, receiver_id, sender_id, parent_id
FROM messages 
GROUP BY parent_id
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

**Note:** No way to fully know if that query works without trying it on your table, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

**Edit:** @liysd made a good point, the order by will merge. You will need to do a subquery against iself.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM messages WHERE parent_id = id)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: this also seems like it should work but didn't work since some of my parent_id values are NULL. sorry i should have mentioned that upfront.

Comment: It doesn't work even if there is no nulls. Fields body, receiver etc. may be from any record not necessary from record with bigest timestamp.

Comment: I don't think it matters if your parent id's are null, you can only match the null values to themselves (ie you cannot match a value from one of the other parent ids that are populated with a value that is null). You will only be able to make matches from records with populated parent_id values.

Answer (score 0):

You may use nested query as below:

```
    select * 
    from messages A 
    where A.receiver_id=:receiver_id
    (and timestamp = (select max(timestamp) 
                     from message B 
                     where A.parent_id = B.parent_id and A.parent_id<>NULL ))
    or A.parent_id = NULL
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working for me. but did you mean to put the ":" between "A.receiver_id=" AND "receiver_id".

Comment: I meant a parameter :receiver_id. You may bind value with use function bindValue. Instead you also may write $receiver_id from PHP or @receiver_id if it's a part of stored procedure.